# Converting a full datetime value to dd/mm/yyyy without time indication on the client

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

I receive this datetime value from my Web API 2 backend:

```
2015-12-11T09:15:49.403
```

That is fine and should remain such, but, on the receiving end (AngularJS) that needs to be converted into:

```
11-12-2015
```

Without the time information, how to achieve this *for an input field*?

Comment: do you mean display it as such? or the model needs to trim the time portion?

Comment: For display, so that a datepicker would work correctly.

Comment: Use ng filter component of date such as `{{input_date | date:dd-MM-yyyy}}`

For more formats visit `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date`

Answer (score 0):

You can save with string format in your database as follow this

dateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Really you can't achieve DateTime format whit this dd-MM-yyyy, becous in your database will saved for example 11-12-2015 00:00:00

Comment: For display purpose, we can always use the ng-filter Date component irrespective of the fact how it is saved in backend. Simply add    ` date:''dd-MM-yyyy'` component to the html tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use a filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <span>{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you use it with an input field?

Comment: actually you didn't mention needing to use it in an input field. The above solution won't work for that.